# Appending Date Picker Selection to a Text Area

Tags: javafx, datepicker, scenebuilder

I am using JavaFX with Scene Builder

I cannot figure out how to append a selected date from a datepicker to a text area.

Here is the code to append a text field to a text area

```
txtPropertyCode.setOnAction((event) ->{
            txtDisplayArea.appendText(txtPropertyCode.getText());
```

If I replace the txtPropertyCode with registrationDatePicker it gives an error because the rest of the code is not in line for what is needed for the Date Picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference should be that `DatePicker` doesn't define a `getText` method. Instead, it inherits a [`getValue()` method from `ComboBoxBase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#getValue--) that returns a `LocalDate`. So you can do

```
registrationDatePicker.setOnAction(event -> 
    txtDisplayArea.appendText(registrationDatePicker.getValue().toString()));
```

Comment: You wouldn't by chance know how to append to an Excel file to where each piece of data gets its own cell?